# Javascript global variable undeclared problem

Tags: javascript

In the mentioned sample code I'm trying to get a value for val variable. I declared it with global scope. And add some console log to verify values. But inside of the function it assign value without problem. But out of the function val is undeclared. why is that?

```
$.validator.addMethod("serialverify", function(){
                var val;
                $("#serialno").keyup(function(){
                    serial().done(function(data){
                        console.log('final = ' + data);
                        val = data;
                        console.log(val);
                    });
                }); console.log(val);
                return val;
            }, "Please enter valid serial code");
```

Comment: *"I declared it with global scope."* No you didn't.

Comment: doesn't seem like your `val` variable is global

Comment: `return val` will always produce null as your assignment is taking place in a presumably asynchronous callback `serial().done()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fundamental problem in your code. The assignment is taking place in a callback function, which means it'll only execute when the action `keyup` is made.

However, the statement `return val` is happening synchronously.

Suggestion -

You can wrap it in a promise of some sort and `resolve` it when `done` is executed. Something on the lines of -

```
......done( function(data) { ..... resolve(val); })
```

or declare `var val`; as global that is outside, the `addMethod` function

Comment: oh. I'm stupid.. @Aseem thanks a lot friend.. now I got it.